# Unable to verify the Signed Hash in C++ from VB.Net

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, encryption, hash

My requirement is to verify the signed hash in my C++ application which was earlier signed in VB.Net !

I ll briefly explain you what I did to achieve it..
First of all I created a Private/Public Key Pair with CspParameters.KeyNumber value = "Signature" and exported its CspBlob to a file "KeyPair.txt" for using the Public Key in my C++ program.

```
 Dim str As testData= "Hello World"
  Dim Hash() As Byte = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1").ComputeHash(testData)
  Hash = RSA.SignHash(Hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"))
  Array.Reverse(Hash)
```

and saved the Signed Hash in a File "Signature.txt" in reverse order for VB.Net to Native CAPI compatibility (Big Endian to Little Endian).

2.)
On other end ( C++ Program) ...

Firstly, I computed the SHA1 of testData "Hello World" and then did used below code for verifying the signature.

```
  BYTE* Message_Digest_SHA1 = SHA1("Hello World");
    BYTE* pbBlob = ReadFile("KeyPair.txt");
    int pbBlobLen = GetFileLen("KeyPair.txt");
    BYTE* pbSignature = ReadFile("Signature.txt");
    int pbSignatureLen = GetFileLen("Signature.txt");

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, 0, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
        {
    //Error checking omitted !
    }


   if (pbBlob) {
            if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, pbBlob, pbBlobLen , 0, 0, &hPubKey))
                return FALSE;
               } 


    HCRYPTHASH hHash;
    if(CryptCreateHash(
       hProv, 
       CALG_SHA1, 
       0, 
       0, 
       &hHash)) 
    {
         printf("The hash object has been recreated. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }

    if(CryptHashData(
       hHash, 
       Message_Digest_SHA1 , 
       20, // length of message digest
       0)) 
    {
         printf("The new hash has been created.\n");
    }
    else
    {
         //Error
    }

    if(CryptVerifySignature(
       hHash, 
       pbSignature, 
       pbSignatureLen , 
       hPubKey,
       NULL, 
       0)) 
    {
         printf("The signature has been verified.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError(); // 2148073478   in HEX 0x80090006  NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE
         printf("Signature not validated!\n");
    }


    if(hHash) 
      CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
```

But, CryptVerifySignature fails with NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE !
Can you please look into my code and point out my mistake

Thank you.

Comment: I strongly suspect you shouldn't be reversing the hash... it's just a sequence of bytes, not a number to be considered as little-endian or big-endian...

Comment: @JonSkeet Pls refer this MSDN link , if it could help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx#remarksToggle

Comment: Interesting, but that says it's for encryption rather than signing. Have you at least *tried* not reversing it?

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways !
Infact , also came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015408/digital-signature-made-in-c-sharp-does-not-verify-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Right. Just as an aside, your "C#" code  appears to be a mixture of C# and VB, and your C++ code appears to be invalid (look at the arguments to ReadFile for example). Can you post short but *complete and valid* C# and C++ programs which demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Pls consider the .NET code in VB, and I just added the File Reading functions for reference , these are not actual functions, except those functions all the Code is Actual.

Comment: Without real code, it's going to be very hard to reproduce the problem. With short but complete programs we're likely to be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to hash twice. Once in

```
BYTE* Message_Digest_SHA1 = SHA1("Hello World");
```

then again in

```
CryptHashData(hHash, Message_Digest_SHA1, 20,0)
```

I suspect you need to hash only once. I would recommend removing the first one as the signature method expects a reference to a hash object. Supply the *correct binary encoding* of `"Hello World"` as data instead.

Comment: Note that I don't see any `ComputeHash` method for strings, so pretty please with sugar on top, provide us with an SSCCE (or two).